# Using Azure Mobile Service SDK instead of Volley

Tags: android, azure, azure-mobile-services

I am developing an android application using Asp.Net Web api as a backend service. Up to now, I made my whole requests from android client to web api service using Volley and built my framework according to this perspective. However, while reading some documents about Azure platform. I find out Azure Mobile Services and its own Android SDK like MobileClient and in document says that we can also use this SDK in our native android application and it brings in cloud sync, authentication, etc.

My system already works and changing my android application to Azure Mobile Service SDK causes lots of extra effort. It is worth it?, or does Azure Mobile Services SDK make my android application more scalable, secure, etc.